# Adding margin / padding to background: cover?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a new website that adds a fullscreen image to the `body` class using `background: cover`.

It works well but I want to change it as currently, some of the background image is concealed by the header and footer. I thought about adding a top margin but this didn't work.

Comment: (Hi Charly. I've just removed a broken link from this question. It is worth storing illustrative images on the official Stack Overflow CDN where you can, to avoid questions being rendered unclear when an external site goes down, or content is changed or deleted. If you need to illustrate something dynamic, use a JS Fiddle or other demo site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to add the `background-image` to the `<div>`/`<section>`/`<main>` that contains your content.

Of course if you do that, you'll have to make sure that:

- there is no margin between `<header>` and `<main>` or between `<main>` and `<footer>`
- `<main>` is full-width
- `<main>` is tall enough
- `<footer>` doesn't overlap with a part of your background image that is important to you

Alternatively, if you know the height of your `<header>` you might also be able to position your `background-image`:

```
header {
    height:100px;
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must move your background from `<body>` to `<div id="section-content">`

Answer (score 0):

You could move the background cover image to the #section-content div, but that will only stop the header from overlapping.

Your .sixteen class has a height set to 100%, which in your case will always force it under the footer.

The layout needs to be rethought a bit.

In my experience, when using an adjustable sized box like this with a background image, I end up using jQuery to resize the div dynamically.

Here is an example: http://www.weloveteachers.org/